# NodeJS v8.12.0-x64 FOR LOOP unexpected results

Tags: node.js, for-loop

Is **"i"** a reserved variable?  May seem like an unlikely question.  However, when I run the following simple code on my computer and the iteration variable used in the FOR loop is set as **"i"**, after the first execution of the loop **"i"** comes back as **63**.

When **"i"** is changed to **z, omega, or some other variable** name the loop operates as expected.  Am I missing something?  Is this an issue with my computer?

```
/*
This javascript code demonstrates a simple encode/decode of a string using a hash of possible values
    stored in a JSON object.
*/

objPossibleCharacters = {
    "Z" : "c",          "Y" : "i",          "X" : "P",          "W" : "O",
    "V" : "b",          "U" : "5",          "T" : "V",          "S" : "a",
    "R" : "4",          "Q" : "Z",          "P" : "U",          "O" : "h",
    "N" : "d",          "M" : "R",          "L" : "3",          "K" : "N",
    "J" : "E",          "I" : "w",          "H" : "D",          "G" : "2",
    "F" : "e",          "E" : "v",          "D" : "q",          "C" : "j",
    "B" : "Q",          "A" : "1",          "0" : "G",          "1" : "f",
    "2" : "C",          "3" : "F",          "4" : "o",          "5" : "M",
    "6" : "0",          "7" : "r",          "8" : "L",          "9" : "H",
    "a" : "g",          "b" : "6",          "c" : "s",          "d" : "m",
    "e" : "S",          "f" : "7",          "g" : "x",          "h" : "p",
    "i" : "X",          "j" : "B",          "k" : "8",          "l" : "I",
    "m" : "y",          "n" : "T",          "o" : "k",          "p" : "J",
    "q" : "W",          "r" : "z",          "s" : "K",          "t" : "l",
    "u" : "t",          "v" : "9",          "w" : "A",          "x" : "Y",
    "y" : "u",          "z" : "n",          "!" : "%",          "?" : "~",
    "," : "*",          "." : "$",          " " : "|"
};

function encodeString( str ){
    encodedStr = "";
    for (i=0; i < str.length; i++){
        encodedStr += objPossibleCharacters[str.charAt(i)];
    }
    //console.log( encodedStr );
    return encodedStr;
}

function decodedString( str ){
    decodedStr = "";
    value = "";
    for ( i=0; i < str.length; i++ ){
        value = str.charAt(i);
        decodedStr += getKeyByValue( value );
    }
    //console.log( decodedStr );
    return decodedStr;
}

function getKeyByValue( value ){
    for ( key in objPossibleCharacters ){
        if ( objPossibleCharacters.hasOwnProperty( key ) ){

            if ( objPossibleCharacters[key] === value ) return key;
        }
    }
}

var strArray = [ 
    'Sea shells, sea shells.  She sells sea shells by the sea shore.', 
    'Thank you for coming today.  I hope you found this session enlightening and useful.', 
    'Elvis has left the building.  You do not need to go home, but you cannot stay here.  Get out!' ];

strArrayLength = strArray.length;

// This issue is in the following FOR LOOP
// Change var x = 0 to var i = 0
var x = 0;
for (x=0; x<strArrayLength; ++x){

        str = strArray[x];
        encodedOutput = encodeString( str );
        decodedOutput = decodedString( encodedOutput );

        console.log( "" );
        console.log( "Original string: " +str );
        console.log( "Encoded string: " +encodedOutput );
        console.log( "Decoded string: " +decodedOutput );
        console.log( strArrayLength +" - "+ x );
        console.log( "" );
}
```

When **i** is used as the variable, I only get the following output:

```
Original string: Sea shells, sea shells.  She sells sea shells by the sea shore.
Encoded string: aSg|KpSIIK*|KSg|KpSIIK$||apS|KSIIK|KSg|KpSIIK|6u|lpS|KSg|KpkzS$
Decoded string: Sea shells, sea shells.  She sells sea shells by the sea shore.
3 - 63
```

When a different variable name is used, I get the following output:

```
Original string: Sea shells, sea shells.  She sells sea shells by the sea shore.
Encoded string: aSg|KpSIIK*|KSg|KpSIIK$||apS|KSIIK|KSg|KpSIIK|6u|lpS|KSg|KpkzS$
Decoded string: Sea shells, sea shells.  She sells sea shells by the sea shore.
3 - 0


Original string: Thank you for coming today.  I hope you found this session enlightening and useful.
Encoded string: VpgT8|ukt|7kz|skyXTx|lkmgu$||w|pkJS|ukt|7ktTm|lpXK|KSKKXkT|STIXxplSTXTx|gTm|tKS7tI$
Decoded string: Thank you for coming today.  I hope you found this session enlightening and useful.
3 - 1


Original string: Elvis has left the building.  You do not need to go home, but you cannot stay here.  Get out!
Encoded string: vI9XK|pgK|IS7l|lpS|6tXImXTx$||ikt|mk|Tkl|TSSm|lk|xk|pkyS*|6tl|ukt|sgTTkl|Klgu|pSzS$||2Sl|ktl%
Decoded string: Elvis has left the building.  You do not need to go home, but you cannot stay here.  Get out!
3 - 2
```

Comment: Beware of **"hoisted" variables**, see @robertklep response.  I am just starting to code in javascript regularly and proper variable declarations are a little more important than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your functions don't properly declare the `i` variable. Because `var i = 0` gets [hoisted](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-hoisting-variables), that variable will be shared by all of your functions.

For example:

```
function encodeString( str ){
  encodedStr = "";
  for (i=0; i < str.length; i++){ ... }
}
```

Proper declaration:

```
function encodeString( str ){
  let encodedStr = "";
  for (let i=0; i < str.length; i++){ ... }
}
```

The same goes for other variables that you're using too.

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware of variable hoisting.  I operated under the paradigm that variables stayed within the scope of their code block.  The link on hoisted variables yielded the following:  **all undeclared variables are global variables.**  I did not realize this.  I declared "i" with the "var" reserved word in each of the other FOR LOOPS and now the code operates as expected.  **Let this be a lesson on declaring variables properly.**

Comment: Okay Robert, I have the code working properly now (declaring "i" within their scope).  However, as I attempted to solve where the "63" was coming from the only logical answer I can get to is the **for ( key in objPossibleCharacters ){ ... }**.  With that said, my code is not using the "i" variable in it.  So, is the underlying logic of the **for ( ... ) { ... }** returning that "i"?  If so, should I have expected it?

Comment: The **"!" : "%",** in the **objPossibleCharacters** object is in the appropriate spot to yield this **"63"** result **AND** the 3rd string ends with an **"!"**.  Hmmm...

Comment: @EricG undeclared variables yield unexpected results. Those results might be _explainable_, but that would require analysing the code much better than I did, to be honest :D